# C# Winform application to play music throughout the separate forms

Tags: c#, audio

SoundPlayerManager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Resources;

public class SoundPlayerManager
{
    private static SoundPlayerManager instance;
    private SoundPlayer[] soundPlayers;
    private int currentSoundPlayerIndex = 0;

    public static SoundPlayerManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new SoundPlayerManager();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private SoundPlayerManager()
    {
        InitializeSoundPlayers();
    }

    private void InitializeSoundPlayers()
    {
        soundPlayers = new SoundPlayer[]
        {
                new SoundPlayer("all_girls_are_the_same.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("armed_and_dangerous.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("bad_boy.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("bandit_og.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("bottle.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("coconut_mall.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("final_battle.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("flower_garden.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("glock_handler.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("gopro.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("gourmet_race.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("iron_on_me.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("jeffrey.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("nobody.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("nuketown.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("racks_in.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("racks_out.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("soda_pop.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("spanglish.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("stumblin.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("toxic_humans.wav"),
                new SoundPlayer("wii_shop.wav")
        };
    }

    public void PlayCurrentSoundPlayer()
    {
        if (currentSoundPlayerIndex >= 0 && currentSoundPlayerIndex < soundPlayers.Length)
        {
            soundPlayers[currentSoundPlayerIndex].Play();
        }
    }

    public void PauseCurrentSoundPlayer()
    {
        if (currentSoundPlayerIndex >= 0 && currentSoundPlayerIndex < soundPlayers.Length)
        {
            soundPlayers[currentSoundPlayerIndex].Stop();
        }
    }

    public void SkipToNextSoundPlayer()
    {
        PauseCurrentSoundPlayer();

        // Shuffle the sound players
        var random = new Random();
        soundPlayers = soundPlayers.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).ToArray();

        // Reset the current sound player index to play the first shuffled sound
        currentSoundPlayerIndex = 0;

        PlayCurrentSoundPlayer();
    }
}
```

Main.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Media;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static Siticone.Desktop.UI.WinForms.Suite.Descriptions;
using System.Resources;

namespace KeyAuth
{

    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        private SoundPlayerManager soundPlayerManager;

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            soundPlayerManager = SoundPlayerManager.Instance;
            // Initialize the array of SoundPlayer objects with the audio files
        } // LOADING MAIN

        private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        } // MAIN LOAD

        private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Turn me up. A LOT!", "999");
            soundPlayerManager.PlayCurrentSoundPlayer();
        } // PLAY BUTTON

        private void pauseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            soundPlayerManager.PauseCurrentSoundPlayer();
        } // PAUSE BUTTON

        private void skipButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            soundPlayerManager.SkipToNextSoundPlayer();
        } // SKIP BUTTON
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help. As I mention this is working when running in Visual Studio although not when exporting for release.

I have had luck mostly with the SoundPlayer code so far although when releasing the build I get the windows error "Please be sure a sound file exists at the specified location."

This is working when running it in the Visual Studio software although when building the exe for release and running the exe from a different location it gives the Windows error I mentioned. I'm using the Fody nuget package that works with the exe export. Greatly appreciate any help.

Here I will give some of the code and the .wav sound files are embedded resources placed many times throughout the folders of the application files to see if it could be read from any of the different locations (Resources, Debug, Release, etc).

I've removed small parts of the code that isn't required for this part of the application.

EDIT:

This worked although only for the single audio file.

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.Stream = YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.Properties.Resources.YOUR_FILE_NAME;
player.Play();
```

How could I get it to play multiple for a list of different songs?

Comment: Edit added to the post.

Comment: "This worked although only for the single audio file." What's stopping you from using a `List<SoundPlayer>`, creating those instances in the manner you said "works", and adding them to the List?

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed with the help of @Idle_Mind 's comment.

Here's the code for anyone else that wants to know of course replace my file references with your own.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Resources;

public class SoundPlayerManager
{
    private static SoundPlayerManager instance;

    private int currentSoundPlayerIndex = 0;
    private List<SoundPlayer> soundPlayers = new List<SoundPlayer>();
    public event EventHandler PlayRandomSongEvent;

    private SoundPlayerManager()
    {
        InitializeSoundPlayers();
    }

    public static SoundPlayerManager GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new SoundPlayerManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private void InitializeSoundPlayers()
    {
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.all_girls_are_the_same));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.armed_and_dangerous));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.all_girls_are_the_same));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.armed_and_dangerous));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.bad_boy));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.bandit_og));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.bottle));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.coconut_mall));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.final_battle));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.flower_garden));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.glock_handler));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.gopro));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.gourmet_race));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.iron_on_me));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.jeffrey));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.nobody));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.nuketown));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.racks_in));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.racks_out));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.soda_pop));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.spanglish));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.stumblin));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.toxic_humans));
        soundPlayers.Add(new SoundPlayer(modding.Properties.Resources.wii_shop));
        // Add more sound files as needed
    }

    private void NextSong(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentSoundPlayerIndex = (currentSoundPlayerIndex + 1) % soundPlayers.Count;
        soundPlayers[currentSoundPlayerIndex].Play();
    }

    public void PlayRandomSong()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.Next(0, soundPlayers.Count);
        soundPlayers[index].Play();
        currentSoundPlayerIndex = (currentSoundPlayerIndex + 1) % soundPlayers.Count;
    }

    public void PauseCurrentSong()
    {
        soundPlayers[currentSoundPlayerIndex].Stop();
    }

    public void SkipToNextSong()
    {
        currentSoundPlayerIndex = (currentSoundPlayerIndex + 1) % soundPlayers.Count;
        soundPlayers[currentSoundPlayerIndex].Play();
    }
}

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Media;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static Siticone.Desktop.UI.WinForms.Suite.Descriptions;
using System.Resources;
using DevExpress.XtraWaitForm;

namespace KeyAuth
{


    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        private SoundPlayerManager soundPlayerManager;

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            soundPlayerManager = SoundPlayerManager.GetInstance();
        } // LOADING MAIN

        private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Turn me up. A LOT!", "999");
            soundPlayerManager.PlayRandomSong();
        } // PLAY BUTTON

        private void pauseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            soundPlayerManager.PauseCurrentSong();
        } // PAUSE BUTTON

        private void skipButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            soundPlayerManager.SkipToNextSong();
        } // Skip button click event handler
    }
}
```